# How can I pass a double array to a form and use it in multiple subs?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, forms

I already searched a lot but could not find a solution. I have a Form and in that Form I call another Form (let's say Form2). In Form 2 I can enter values in some textboxes and then I am passing these values as a double array back to Form 1:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim a As Double
  Dim userDefined(3) As Double
  Dim Form_2 As Form2
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Form_2= New Form2       
    Form_2.ShowDialog()
    a = userDefined(0)

  End Sub

  Public WriteOnly Property setUserValues As Array
    Set(value As Array)

        userDefined = value

    End Set
  End Property
End Class


Public Class Form2
  Dim userDefined(0 To 3) As Double

Private Sub Btn_transmitValues_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_transmitValues.Click

    userDefined(0) = Txt_1.Text
    userDefined(1) = Txt_2.Text
    userDefined(2) = Txt_3.Text
    userDefined(3) = Txt_4.Text

    Form1.setUserValues = userDefined

    Me.Dispose()

End Sub

End Class
```

Now I want to use the values from the passed double array of Form2 in Form1 in the Button1_Click Sub. But when I define my array in Form1 as

```
Dim userDefined(3) As Double
```

then a (also in Form1) is always 0. When I define my array in Form 1 as

```
Dim userDefined() As Double
```

then I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" but when I hover over a the right value is passed. What can I do to get the right value for a? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont use default names, you need to use instances... Theres more than one issue here as well. As of now, form2 doesnt know about form1 instance. So in short, form2 needs to take form1 instance so it can work with  it. In form2 you need a new constuctor that takes the form1 instance...

Comment: I really don't know what exactly you mean. Can you maybe give me a code sample? The thing is that the other way round it works. So if I create a Read Only Property in Form1 and call it in Form2 then I get all the values I want out of Form1

Answer (score 1):

So I got it working but I dont know if this is a good style. Maybe anyone can tell if this is good or bad coding. I basically just changed the way the variables are being passed. First I had Form2 write the new variables into the array of Form1, now I have Form1 reading the values out of Form2.

The thing I don't link myself is, that the variables are being calculated in Form2, then Form2 is being disposed and after that the variables are getting read. Maybe this could problematic because I call variables of a closed Form?

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim a As Double
  Dim userDefined(3) As Double
  Dim Form_2 As Form2

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Form_2= New Form2       
    Form_2.ShowDialog()
    userDefined = Form_2.getUserDefined

    a = userDefined(0)

  End Sub

End Class
```

And Form 2:

```
Public Class Form2
  Dim _userDefined(0 To 3) As Double

Private Sub Btn_transmitValues_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_transmitValues.Click

    _userDefined(0) = Txt_1.Text
    _userDefined(1) = Txt_2.Text
    _userDefined(2) = Txt_3.Text
    _userDefined(3) = Txt_4.Text

    Me.Dispose()

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property getUserDefined As Double()
    Get
        Return _userDefined
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

A nice easy way is to add a proprty in Form_2 such as

```
Public Property userDefined() as Double
```

Then in Form one, where you have

```
Form_2= New Form2       
Form_2.ShowDialog()
```

add this inbetwen the two lines -

```
Form_2.userDefined= userDefined
```

You may need to add code into the Form_2.Shown event to update any controls if the array affects any controls as soon as the form is shown, but that's about it.